# ntp_gettime() returns code 5

Tags: ubuntu, ntp, ntpd

I'm trying syncronize clock on ubuntu server with commands:

```
$sudo apt-get install ntp
$sudo service ntp stop
$sudo ntpd -gq
$sudo service ntp start
```

But it anyway gives me:

```
$sudo ntptime
ntp_gettime() returns code 5 (ERROR)
  time dd8ee7a9.ff3c9258  Mon, Oct 16 2017  8:09:13.997, (.997018034),
  maximum error 16000000 us, estimated error 16000000 us, TAI offset 0
ntp_adjtime() returns code 5 (ERROR)
  modes 0x0 (),
  offset 0.000 us, frequency 275.646 ppm, interval 1 s,
  maximum error 16000000 us, estimated error 16000000 us,
  status 0x2041 (PLL,UNSYNC,NANO),
  time constant 3, precision 0.001 us, tolerance 500 ppm,
```

Comment: What's the output of ntpq -p ?

Comment: @bgtvfr `0.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000`. And restart of linux helped to solve this issue.

Comment: Your issue was solved by rebooting the box. Therefore, we won't be able to determine the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @Nikita What command ran you or changed configurations where ?

Comment: @ChamindaBandara unfortunately, the only reboot of the node helped in my case. Didn't have enough time to find a better option on production node :(